# Display data in table from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to manually create a table in asp.net to display data from a mssql database. I have set up a connection like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server = servername; uid = username; pwd = password; database = database;");
 connection.Open();
```

So I need to know a simple way to use this connection to display data in a table. I then want to be able to edit the data in this database, as well as add new data.

Comment: a google search returns a ton of options for this, have you tried any of those? If so what types of errors are you getting.

Comment: I've searched a lot and not getting any good answeres. If you can redirect me to something I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a place you can start.  If you need specific help update the question with more details about what's going on.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719634(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719634%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)